# create a global reference in JNA

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, jna

The native library I want to use have method like this:

```
extern unsigned long write(void);
```

what it is going to write, however, need to be defined in several global variable:

```
short int Addr; //the starting address it write to;
short int Length; //the length of the writing;
void * data; //the data it will write;
```

I know in JNA, the NativeLibray have method to load global reference defined in the native library, but it seems not what it needed here. I actually need to declare the above global variables and write to them, so that the write() method can work properly.

Any suggestion on how to implement this in JNA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So many game hackers unwilling to get into dirty details.

`NativeLibrary` provides access to the addresses of global variables exported by a shared library.

```
NativeLibrary lib = NativeLibray.getInstance("mylib");
Pointer paddr = lib.getGlobalVariableAddress("Addr");
paddr.setInt(0, 1234);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just wrap you "write" method in another one that you can call via Java/JNA. In there, you first set those global variables and then call the real one.

Comment: well, it is not "my" write method, and I don't really want to touch C unless JNA doesn't have a solution for this.